# javascript extract html block from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string extracted from a div and stored in variable "str". I now need to extract the `<a href="blah">...</a>` subset of it.

```
str = '<div id="xyz"><p>This is a paragraph</p><a href="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=brd&FlightID=2997227&Page=&PluID=0&Pos=9088" target="_blank"><img src="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=bsr&FlightID=2997227&Page=&PluID=0&Pos=9088" border=0 width=300 height=250></a></div>';
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: One thing that may help with the answers: do you really want to operate on the string itself? Or do you want to extract the information from the DOM?  If the former, are there any rules for how the string is formed?  That is, is href the first or only attribute?  How many a tags are there in the string?

Answer (score 2):

1. make it innerHTML of a temporary div.
2. use getElementsByTagName("A") to retreive all "A" nodes.
3. get their HTML .

Here is a running example : http://jsfiddle.net/3fZch/

```
var str = '<div id="xyz"><p>This is a paragraph</p><a href="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=brd&FlightID=2997227&Page=&PluID=0&Pos=9088" target="_blank"><img src="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=bsr&FlightID=2997227&Page=&PluID=0&Pos=9088" border=0 width=300 height=250></a></div>';


var newElem = returnTheParentNode(str);
var anchors = newElem.getElementsByTagName('A');
/* anchors has all the a tags of the html string */
    for(var i = 0 ; i < anchors.length ; i++)
    {
      var aHTML = getHTML(anchors[i]);
      alert(aHTML);   
    }




function returnTheParentNode(htmlStr)
{
var myCont = document.createElement('DIV'); // create a div element
myCont.innerHTML = htmlStr; // create its children with the string
return myCont;  // return the parent div

}

function getHTML(theNode)
{
    var myCont = document.createElement('DIV');
    myCont.insertBefore(theNode,null);
    return myCont.innerHTML ;
}
```

Comment: Better make this temporary *div* invisible (with `display:none` for instance) too !

Comment: +1 but perhaps didn't qutie finish the job. If the OP wants the A elements as HTML, then put each A into a temp div and get the div's innerHTML. Don't use regular expressions, they'll probably fail in some cases.

Comment: @Creadiff - no need if the div is never added to the document.

Comment: Indeed, sorry about the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like the below:

`var a = $(str).find('a').html();`

Answer (score 0):

The expression you need is:

```
str.match(/a href="([^"]*)"/)[1]
```

But this assumes there is only one `a` tag in your string and you used double quotes to delimit the href.

Made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eDAuv/

Comment: Also depends on the href appearing as the first attribute - there is no guarantee of that.

Comment: I need the whole outerHTML of the <a> block

Comment: Rob, it's ok. The string will only ever contain one <a> block.

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
var link = $(str).find("a").get(0).outerHTML;
alert(link);
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove EVERYTHING except the hyperlink block? In case the string is different each time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not extract the link BEFORE you store it in a string?

```
myLink = $(".myDiv a").html()
```